# How to do smth in one thread several time until success?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to have a thread for each player to guess a number.
But now I create each time a thread and got an out of memory exception.
How to fix it? How to make one thread to guess number until win.
I want to have as many threads as players and execute the function until someone wins.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object lockObject = new object();
        bool isGameOver = false;

        int weightOfBasket = Game.SetWeightForBasket();
        Console.WriteLine("Real weight : " + weightOfBasket);

        Console.WriteLine("Count of players in this game?");
        var countOfPlayers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var players = new List<IPlayer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            IPlayer player = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Player's name:");
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Player's type:");
            string playerType = Console.ReadLine();
            bool isExist = playerType != null && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Game.Type), value: playerType);
            if (isExist)
            {
                Type type = Type.GetType("TestTask_game." + playerType + "Player");
                if (type != null)
                {
                    player = (IPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                }
                if (player != null)
                {
                    player.Name = playerName;
                    player.Type = playerType;
                    players.Add(player);
                }
            }
        }
        while (!isGameOver)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(players, new ParallelOptions(),
                (player, i, j) =>
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => TryToGuess(player, weightOfBasket, out isGameOver, ref lockObject));
                });
        }
        FindClosestToWinPlayer(players, weightOfBasket);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

 private static void TryToGuess(IPlayer player, int weightOfBasket, out bool IsWinner, ref object objectToLock)
    {
        lock (objectToLock)
        {
            if (_overallAmountOfAttempts == Game.AttemptsLimit)
            {
                IsWinner = true;
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
                return;
            }
            _overallAmountOfAttempts++;

            int numberToGuess = player.GetNumberToGuess();
            Game.AllNumberAttempts.Add(numberToGuess);

            Console.WriteLine("Number is " + numberToGuess + "?");
            Console.WriteLine("Attempt was made by " + player.Name);

            if (numberToGuess == weightOfBasket)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(player.Name + " is a winner. Count of attempts = " + player.CountOfAttempts);
                IsWinner = true;
                Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
            }
            else
            {
                int delta = weightOfBasket - numberToGuess;
                Thread.Sleep(Math.Abs(delta) * 1000);
                IsWinner = false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_overallAmountOfAttempts);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think carefully whether multithreading is what you need, most of the time it's not. It's quite a complicated subject and hard to get right at the best of times.

In your while loop you're creating new threads pretty much constantly, the condition never changes to false during the while loop as far as I can tell. Furthermore, you're locking inside the TryToGuess function on the same object, which makes multithreading pointless anyway - only one thread at a time will enter the lock.

If you really really decide you must have multithreading, the better approach here would be to create a thread for each player only once, then let them run to completion and synchronizing them as they run. Also, use Tasks or some other higher level of abstraction instead of handling the multithreading manually.

Edit: it all seems like a highly serial process anyway - the players take turns, there's just one Console... so that's why I said multithreading is probably not the right approach here.

Edit edit: but if you really really want to use multithreading anyway, for fun or learning I suppose, you have to take into account that a large amount of communication is needed between the player threads and the main thread. They need to know when their turn is, and they need to respond with whether the player won or not. So one reasonable approach I can think of is to have semaphores for each player, and signal the semaphore when it's the player's turn, then that thread runs, then the main thread checks some shared state to see if it should stop (either after each player or after one turn), which means the main thread needs to wait until the player threads finish one turn. I don't really see alternatives that don't defeat the purpose of multithreading, sorry :)

Comment: I exactly don't understand how to run several times a function in one thread until success?

Comment: You would run it in a while loop or something similar, same as any other code. For instance `while (true) { mySemaphore.WaitOne(); /* do stuff */ mySemaphore.Release(); if (condition) break; }` (I just typed this without thinking so please don't take it as an example of best practice)